# C++ Template Help

Tags: c++, templates

I think my issues are Template related but I just dont know. I am geting errors like:

`error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FxStreamable* (***)(), std::vector<FxStreamable* (**)(), std::allocator<FxStreamable* (**)()> > >' to non-scalar type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<FxClassID, FxStreamable* (*)()>*, std::vector<std::pair<FxClassID, FxStreamable* (*)()>, std::allocator<std::pair<FxClassID, FxStreamable* (*)()> > > >' requested`

and

`no match for 'operator!=' in 'itera1 != ((FxPairRegistry<FxClassID, FxStreamable* (*)()>*)this)->FxPairRegistry<FxClassID, FxStreamable* (*)()>::mRegistryList. std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = FxStreamable* (**)(), _Alloc = std::allocator<FxStreamable* (**)()>]()'`

in code that looks like

```
for (iter itera1 = mRegistryList.begin(); itera1 != mRegistryList.end(); itera1++)
{
    if ((*itera1).first == id)
    {
        return (*itera1).second;
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is going wrong?

UPDATE: mRegistryList is defined  `vector<registeredObject *> mRegistryList;`

UPDATE: itera is define `typedef typename std::vector<pair<identifier,registeredObject> >::iterator iter;`

UPDATE 3:

```
template <class identifier,class registeredObject> registeredObject     FxPairRegistry<identifier,registeredObject>::GetEntry(identifier id, FxBool assertValue)
{
for (std::vector<registeredObject *>::iterator itera1 = mRegistryList.begin(); itera1 != mRegistryList.end(); itera1++)
{
    if ((*itera1).first == id)
    {
        return (*itera1).second;
    }
}

if (assertValue)
    ASSERT_MSG(0,"Entry not found in the registry");
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What is mRegistryList and how did you define itera1?

Comment: Please edit & paste definition for `mRegistryList`.

Comment: Could you add the declarations of mRegistryList and itera1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your iterator type doesn't match the `mRegistryList` `vector`'s iterator type.

iterator: `std::vector<std::pair<FxClassID, FxStreamable* (*)()> >::iterator`

container: `std::vector<FxStreamable* (**)()>`

EDIT: In response to update:

Use `vector<registeredObject *>::iterator` - not your other unrelated iterator.

In order to iterate over a `vector<X>` container, you need a `vector<X>::iterator` not a `vector<SomethingElse>::iterator`

EDIT: In response to new update:

```
for (typename std::vector<registeredObject *>::iterator itera1 = mRegistryList.begin(); itera1 != mRegistryList.end(); itera1++)
     ^^^^^^^^
```

Since this code is in a template, the compiler doesn't know that `std::vector<registeredObject *>::iterator` is a type - you have to tell it to treat it as a type by prefixing `typename`

Comment: @Erik, I dont follow what this means

Comment: @JTS: Yep. Your `iter` typedef has no relation to your `mRegistryList` vector at all

Comment: it means your iterator definition should match the definition of the collection it is iterating on. if your container is vector<registeredObject *> then the iterator should be vector<registeredObject *>::iterator

Comment: @Erik, So how do I change my `for` above? `for (vector<registeredObject *>::iterator itera1 = mRegistryList.begin(); itera1 != mRegistryList.end(); itera1++)
 {` Seems wrong

Comment: @JTS: `typedef typename std::vector<registeredObject *>::iterator iter;` - that's the right type for iterating over `mRegistryList`

Comment: @Erik `for (vector<registeredObject *>::iterator itera1 = mRegistryList.begin(); itera1 != mRegistryList.end(); itera1++)` I get a `error: expected `;' before 'itera1'`

Comment: @JTS: If this is in a template, you need `typename vector<registeredObject *>::iterator` - Or use the typedef I posted in a comment above.

Comment: @Erik, I still get the same error I mention a few comments above.

Comment: @Erik, Does Update 3 above help? I am confused as to what is going on.

Comment: @JTS: As said, you need a `typename` there

Comment: @Erik - I get it. So with this, how would I check the first element of the vector standard `.front` doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: @JTS: `begin()` returns an iterator to the first element, `front()` returns a reference to the element itself